# Laços de Repetição no AngularJs Cat Tipos

Tags: angularjs

Como criar um formulário dinâmico no angular, esse formulário é composto por categorias e tipos. Era suposto criar uma `tab` com a diversas categorias e dentro de cada categoria mostrar os tipos.

Abaixo segue o exemplo do código.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-body" id="teste" ng-app="app" ng-init="chargeData()" ng-controller="FormCtrl">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li ng-repeat="category in categories"><a href="#{{category.ClinicalExamCategoryId}}" data-toggle="tab">{{category.clinicalExamCategoryName}}</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" ng-repeat="category2 in categories2" id="{{category2.ClinicalExamCategoryId}}">
                        <br>
                        <div id="{{category2.ClinicalExamCategoryId}}" class="row" ng-init="chargeType(category2.ClinicalExamCategoryId);">
                            <div ng-repeat="type in types " id="{{category2.ClinicalExamCategoryId}}" class="col-xs-6">
                                <div id="{{type.ClinicalExamTypeId}}" class="box box-primary">
                                    <div class="box-header">
                                        <h3 class="box-title" id="{{type.clinicalExamTypeName}}">{{type.clinicalExamTypeName}}</h3>
                                        <div class="box-body">

                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controler:

```
$scope.chargeData = function () {
             $http.get("/ClinicalExams/SelectCategory").success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 $scope.categories = data;
                 $scope.categories2 = data;
             //    chargeType(id);
             }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 $scope.state = "ERRO DE EXECUÇÃO";
             });
         }
         $scope.chargeType = function (id) {
             $http.get("/ClinicalExams/SelectType/"+id).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 $scope.types = data;
             }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                 $scope.state = "ERRO DE EXECUÇÃO";
             });
         }
```

Comment: Todas as Categorias

Comment: Como essas categorias retornam? JSON? Faltou você explicar o que tem de errado no seu código, qual é o problema.

Comment: ele envia via json as categorias. Mas em cada cetegoria deveria fazer uma chamada para ir buscar os tipos correspondentes a essa categoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-repeat="type in types";
```

você deveria usar:

```
ng-repeat="type in types track by type.id";
```

ou até mesmo:

```
ng-repeat="type in types track by $index";
```

Mas como você usa repeat dentro de repeat; faça os testes, acho que você deverá usar a primeira opção, (track by type.id);

Answer (score 0):

Cara, honestamente, eu modificaria meu serviço e já traria o JSON todo montado do modo como é seu menu, com as categorias e as subcategorias numa lista dentro de cada categoria...

Do jeito que você faz, dependendo do tamanho do seu menu, você vai fazer umas 300 requisições para o server.

Porque você não traz já formatado assim

```
{
    categoria: 'categoria1'
    subCategoria: [{
            desricao: 'subCategoria1'
        }]
}
```

Dessa forma, você não precisa chamar o serviço para cada categoria existente, de quebra o seu repeat dentro de repeat ficaria N vezes mais fácil.